# How to configure ipv6 with eui-64 interface id on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, ipv6

Refer to https://netplan.io/reference. There is a key "ipv6-address-generation" with possible values: *eui64* or *stable-privacy*.

However when I tried to add that key on /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp6: false
            addresses: ["2003:b::/64"]
            ipv6-address-generation: eui64
```

There is an error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# netplan apply 
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:6:13: Error in network definition: unknown key 'ipv6-address-generation'
            ipv6-address-generation: eui64
            ^
```

> **Update 1:** I tried to install version 0.99 at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.1/+build/19265900.

I use this configuration:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp6: false
            addresses: ["2003:b::/64"]
            ipv6-address-generation: eui64
    renderer: NetworkManager
```

The error has fixed, but there is no effect, I still did not get eui64 format on my ipv6:

```
# ip a show ens3
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:cb:3b:fd:c3:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2003:b::/64 scope global tentative noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ecb:3bff:fefd:c300/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

, not eui64 format.

Anyone can help me to configure ipv6 with eui-64 interface id on ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ipv6-address-generation` key was introduced in netplan 0.99 but is currently only available for the NetworkManager backend/renderer (which needs to be noted in the documentation...).

If you have NetworkManager installed, you can try configuring `renderer: NetworkManager`. Also, it should have thrown an error if used with the default `networkd` backend/renderer...

Comment: I added a note to the upstream documentation, for future reference: https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan/commit/ec22d54a0063f2dfebfec542e528acc1f06cc2c2

Comment: I tried to use "renderer: NetworkManager", there is no error but, still does not get ipv6 eui format. See update of my question.

Comment: Hi @xdnroot. In the updated YAML config you posted, the `renderer: NetworkManager` needs to be indented to the same level as `ethernets:` (i.e. 4 spaces in your case) – it needs to be a child of the `network:` key.

I confirmed this works on my system:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V3yQ3XNHJ6/

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Maerdian, I have configured like you said and the result also same with yours. But, look up my update or your [http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V3yQ3XNHJ6](paste.ubuntu.com/p/V3yQ3XNHJ6).  Why on the ipv6 global scope, there is only seen the ipv6 prefix, that is 2003:b::/64. not 2003:b::xx:xx:xx/64, which is xx:xx:xx is interface id with eui64 format.

Comment: Hi @xdnroot, the `ipv6-address-generation:` config is applied to auto-generated addresses only (SLAAC/DHCPv6). So if you enable `dhcp6: true`, you should be able to get a eui64 interface id on the global scope, but with a prefix provided by the SLAAC/DHCP – not the static address/prefix you defined... Do I understand correctly that you're trying to have a static prefix (`2003:b::/64`) with eui64 interface id? Unfortunately I think this is currently not possible with netplan and I am not aware of how/if this could be setup with networkd/NetworkManager directly, either.

Comment: okay thank you @Lukas

Answer (score 0):

The `ipv6-address-generation` key is introduced in netplan 0.99 which is currently in bionic-proposed for SRU.  This should reach bionic-updates in within the week. 
 You can track the status at https://launchpad.net/bugs/1871825.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to install version 0.99 at [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.1/+build/19265900](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.1/+build/19265900). I still use same configuration like the above thread. The error has fixed, but there is no effect, I still did not get eui64 format on my ipv6.